# Web API 2- incoming and outgoing datetime problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using Web API2 to communicate with mobile. 
Datetime in response was always containing T eg. [2018-09-26T01:30:37.967] which is UTC. To remove it I converted DateTime zone to iso like this

```
IsoDateTimeConverter converter = new IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,
    DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss"
};
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(converter);
```

Now another problem appeared that Input parameter does not take DateTime without T.
Previously it was working [2018-09-26 01:30:37.967] but not it stopped

I tried with this [2018-09-26T01:30:37.967] it worked. but I don't want it.

Web API should work with [2018-09-26T01:30:37.967] both for incoming and outgoing.

Waiting for help

Comment: Get rid of the single quotes in your DateTimeFormat, at the moment it's expecting something like `2018'-'10'-'12' '09':'52':'23`

Comment: Thanks @phuzi I tried it. but it is same. Response DateTime is returning data without T but for input datetime parameter it is not null because it is still expecting T in datetime data

Answer (score 0):

With little change it worked. just changed yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff

```
IsoDateTimeConverter converter = new IsoDateTimeConverter
            {
                DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,
                DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"
            };
```